# Difference between JSON and SQL

Tags: sql, json

I'm a newbie at web development, so here's a simple question. I've been doing a few tutorials in Django, setting up an SQL database, which is all good. I have now come across the JSON format, which I am not fully understanding. The definition on Wikipedia is: *It is used primarily to transmit data between a server and web application, as an alternative to XML*. Does this mean that JSON is a database like SQL? If not, what is the difference between SQL and JSON?

Thank you!

Comment: This should be all you need: http://www.json.org/

Comment: These are 2 completely different things. SQL is used to communicate with the database. Whereas JSON provides a "standard" way to talk to web services

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSON is data markup format. You use it to define what the data is and means.  eg: This car is blue, it has 4 seats.

```
{
    "colour": "blue",
    "seats": 4
}
```

SQL is a data manipulation language.  You use it to define the operations you want to perform on the data. eg: Find me all the green cars. Change all the red cars to blue cars.

```
select * from cars where colour = 'green'
update cars set colour='blue' where colour='red'
```

A SQL database is a database that uses SQL to query the data stored within, in whatever format that might be. Other types of databases are available.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, but to say it's an "Object Notation" isn't going to help!

Answer (score 3):

They are 2 completely different things.

**SQL** is used to communicate with databases, usually to Create, Update and Delete data entries.

**JSON** provides a *standardized* object notation/structure to talk to web services.

**Why standardized?**

Because JSON is relatively easy to process both on the front end (with javascript) and the backend. With no-SQL databases becoming the norm, JSON/JSON-like documents/objects are being used in the database as well.

Comment: Take out the webservices bit and I agree with you, given you can use JSON in javascript, ajax/http and db/file storage!

Comment: @Liath can you explain why the web services bit is wrong? Might have misused the term I guess.

Comment: It's not wrong, you certainly can use it to talk to WebServices. My point is that you can also use it to store data in MongoDB (for example). Your answer gave the impression that it's only use was to communicate via ajax

Comment: Just a little observation, it's not "CReate, Update and Delete". The acronym CRUD is for "Create, Read, Update and Delete".

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. JSON is the data format in order to pass the data from the sender to the receiver. SQL is the language used by relational databases in order to define data structures and query the information from them. JSON is not associated with any way to store or retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't a database, but there isn't anything stopping you from using JSON in a database. Mongo DB is a database that uses JSON (it's actually BSON behind closed doors) to communicate with the database. If you enjoy using JSON and you understand it, I recommend looking into Mongo!

Answer (score 0):

Please take some time to understand why JSON is best left to being a notation that helps in data transfer.  While it is possible to use it in other ways, it is never the best option for anything other than data transfer.  Use database structures for storage and analysis of data.  JSON is not practical outside of data transfer.