# How do i pick a server-side storage method?

Tags: storage, server-side

I'm looking into creating a Bot for a messaging app, but need some help choosing a database for storing some basic user data.
I would use Json, but saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22071781/7764138) and now I'm wondering what the "best" option is for server-side storage in general in terms of security and efficiency?
**In general**: What should i consider when picking a storage option? Is there a "right" choice in this case?

Comment: Using python in case it's relevant

Comment: Just use google firebase or aws amplify with their nosql db's. Done.